# Pass data from object in class A to class B

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor

New to classes and objects in c++ and trying to learn a few basics

I have the class `TStudent` in which the Name, Surname and Age of `student` are stored, also I have the constructor which is accessed in `main` and inserts in the data.
What I want to do is: having the class `TRegistru`, I have to add my objects data in it, in a way that I can store it there, then I could save the data in  `data.bin` and free the memory from the data, then I want to put the data back in the class and print it out.

The question is: In what way & what is the best way to add my objects in the second class, so that I could eventually work with them in the way I've described in the comments, so that I won't have to change nothing in `main`

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;

class TStudent
{
public:
    string Name, Surname;
    int Age;

    TStudent(string name, string surname, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Age = age;
        cout <<"\n";
    }
};

class TRegistru : public TStudent 
{
public:
    Tregistru()        
};

int main()
{
    TStudent student1("Simion", "Neculae", 21);
    TStudent student2("Elena", "Oprea", 21);
    TRegistru registru(student1);//initialising the object
    registru.add(student2);//adding another one to `registru`
    registru.saving("data.bin")//saving the data in a file
    registru.deletion();//freeing the TRegistru memory
    registru.insertion("data.bin");//inserting the data back it
    registru.introduction();//printing it

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to read about *serialization*. (This looks very much like a "please write all the code for me" question. Expect it to get closed.)

Comment: Ref. [Boost.JSON](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/json/doc/html/index.html) and [Boost.Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). Generic version of that advice: Whenever you need something done that isn't in the standard library, check [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/) first.

Comment: I don't think your `TRegistru` class is properly formed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hence the question is about passing data from A to B, I will not comment on the file handling portion.

This can be done in multiple ways, but here is one of the simplest and most generic. By calling TRegistru::toString() you serialize every TStudent added to TRegistru into a single string which then can be easily written to a file.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1KWT1rnjP)

```
class TStudent
{
public:
    std::string Name, Surname;
    int Age;

    std::string toString() const
    {
        return Name + ";" + Surname + ";" + to_string(Age);
    }
};


class TRegistru
{
public:
    void add(const TStudent& student) 
    {
        students.push_back(student);
    }

    void deletion() 
    {
        students.clear();
    }

    std::string toString() const
    {
        std::string ret{};
        for(const auto& student : students)
        {
            ret += student.toString() + "\n";
        }
        return ret;
    }

    std::vector<TStudent> students;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but in main when calling `registru` in gives me an error, I guess it appeals to the constructor, but i don't know why it fails to move on

Comment: @Vlad Here you have a working demo: https://godbolt.org/z/1KWT1rnjP

Comment: yup, thank you, that one kinda helped, but the main point is that `main` should remain untouched

Comment: @Vlad, there is no reason to modify main. You just have to implement saving() method, that will call toString() to serialize TRegistru and write the resulting string to a file. Then again, you can write similar function fromString(const std::string& input) that deserializes a string and creates TStudent instances based on the data you read from that string. In this case it's pretty simple, look for tokenizing or spliting strings by delimiter, there are plenty of code snippets here that show how to do that.